# Azure Active Directory Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, active-directory, forms-authentication

WAAD login page just does not seem right, especially because of branding. Is it possible to use the WAAD default domain in web.config of a MVC app with forms authentication. For instance:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WAAD" connectionString="LDAP://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com:389"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried and get Configuration Error `Unable to establish secure connection with the server.`

Answer (score 1):

Azure Active Directory can provide you with a claims-based experience but not a forms-based one.  You can't yet customise the Azure login page and there's no capability to make an LDAP-based connection to WAAD.

Comment: Simon, thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate on claims based experience? Can I make some claims for the user who signed onto on-premises domain, and send those claims to WAAD server? What assembly/namespace do I use?

Comment: You should look at Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) though with .Net 4.5 this now integrated into the core .Net Framework.  If you want to integrate with an on-premise directory you probably need to look at leveraging ADFS.  In a claim-based auth scenario the user can still be prompted to login using a web form but this form is centralised and not necessarily a part of your app.  I'd recommend doing some reading on the basics of claims-based auth - there's quite a lot online about how it works.